# android youtube api volley exception

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-volley

I was using the Android youtube api and built some nice apps,
 recently I get the following exception when trying to cue a playlist

```
09-28 16:38:37.537: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(13166): apps.youtube.datalib.b.a.b:174 Could not do device auth handshake: 
09-28 16:38:37.537: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(13166): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
09-28 16:38:37.537: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(13166):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.v.a(SourceFile:121)
09-28 16:38:37.537: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(13166):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.v.get(SourceFile:97)
09-28 16:38:37.537: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(13166):   at com.google.android.apps.youtube.datalib.b.a.b(SourceFile:155)
09-28 16:38:37.537: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(13166):   at com.google.android.apps.youtube.datalib.b.a.a(SourceFile:196)
09-28 16:38:37.537: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(13166):   at com.google.android.apps.youtube.datalib.innertube.f.h(SourceFile:95)
09-28 16:38:37.537: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(13166):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.d.a(SourceFile:75)
09-28 16:38:37.537: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(13166):   at com.android.volley.toolbox.a.a(SourceFile:93)
09-28 16:38:37.537: E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI(13166):   at com.android.volley.i.run(SourceFile:105)
```

This exception always appear now, sometimes the playlist loads, and sometimes it doesn't
Any clue, anyone?

Comment: Hello , did you get the solution to this issue ?

Comment: Hey @prateek sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't prbbly Youtube-Android API problems

Comment: Yup you are right but i tried with the suggestion provided by CzarMatt and then after a while it started working

Comment: @prateek - I did it, no success

Comment: Hi @prateek I have the same problem here since yesterday. All the keys and certificates look fine, and CzarMatt's solution didn't help :-(

Comment: @Michael I will take some time to propagate but what I would suggest is to check you apps package name and verify it with the google app console.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when loading my application onto a brand new device.  After approximately one hour, the error disappeared and YouTube API calls were populating in my application.  Perhaps the new device hadn't propagated through Google's servers yet.  Double check to make sure that your API key, app package name and SHA1 certificate fingerprint are correct.  I'd suggest a complete uninstall/install of your application and then trying again after waiting a bit.